# Links being ignored on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I built a WordPress custom theme and am having trouble with the mobile menu items specifically on iOS devices. The mobile menu can be toggled by clicking an element that adds the 'move-left' class to the mobile menu making it visible. When I click on the links on a mobile device (not iOS) the links direct to their pages. However, when I touch the links on an iOS device the 'move-left' class making the menu visible is removed, ignoring the links completely. When I inspect it in BrowserStack, and hover over the  content, the inspector doesn't highlight the content on the iOS device.

The site I need help with: https://www.themissionofhermanstern.org/

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap move-left" data-offcanvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu" aria-hidden="true">
      <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="off-canvas-list">
       <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-40">
        <a href="/about">About</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the storing the cache of the website on your phone. I opend your website on my IPhone. It seemed to be working the way you want.

If you are using IPhone -
Here is a way you could fix this:

1. Open the page in private mode (and bookmark it so you can open it later).
2. When you need to refresh, close browser "tab" (you can stay in Safari and private mode).
3. Open the page again (use the bookmark you created in step 1).

Comment: Thank you! however, I tried that out on my iPhone 6S and it still isn't working correctly.